# Colored manpages with tcsh?

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh, manpage

I really like the colored manpages which can are achieved by

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;33m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[01;32m'
```

in your .bashrc or .zshrc.
My question is: How do I export these variables in tcsh? I have to use tcsh at work and cannot get it working. I tried plenty of variations, but nothing worked. Simply replacing export with setenv and = with " " doesn't do the trick.
But it should work somehow. If i start a tcsh out of my zsh with this exports set I can enjoy colored manpages in tcsh, also. But that's an ugly workaround.

Comment: You'd likely be better off asking this over at superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that tcsh isn't interpreting the escape sequence in your variable name, so the environment variable ends up with a literal `\E` in it when you try to set it with tcsh.  Here's one way you can get around that, using Bash to interpret the escape sequences, although it's a little ugly:

```
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_md `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[01;31m"'`
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_me `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[0m"'`
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_se `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[0m"'`
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_so `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[01;44;33m"'`
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_ue `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[0m"'`
% setenv LESS_TERMCAP_us `bash -c 'echo -en "\e[01;32m"'`
```

Comment: I agree, it's a little ugly, but it works. Though, I let the question's status open, maybe we get a native solution.

Comment: You could do this without using bash (depending on the setting of `echo_style`.

Answer (score 6):

The way to do this which is native to `tcsh` and is portable to different terminal types is to use the `echotc` builtin command:

```
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_mb `echotc md; echotc AF 1`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_md `echotc md; echotc AF 1`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_me `echotc me`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_se `echotc me`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_so `echotc md; echotc AF 3; echotc AB 4`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_ue `echotc me`
setenv LESS_TERMCAP_us `echotc md; echotc AF 2`
```

See [`man 5 terminfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) for the `termcap` codes and color codes.

`md` is `enter_bold_mode`
`me` is `exit_attribute_mode`
`AF` is `set_a_foreground`
`AB` is `set_a_background`

By the way, to do this in Bash, use the external utility `tput` and the terminfo capability names:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput bold; tput setaf 3; tput setab 4)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(tput bold; tput setaf 2)
```

Comment: On my older version of tcsh (6.15.00) I had to add 2 arguments for AF and AB.  I just repeated the numbers (`AF 3 3`, etc.) and it seemed to work well.